# How to change from default theme to other themeTheme.Material.Light

Tags: xamarin.android

I change the manifest file to use the following theme:
change from:
**@style/AppTheme**
to
**@style/Theme.Material.Light**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="App1.App1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" **android:theme="@style/Theme.Material.Light"></application>
</manifest>
```

But when building and deploying got the following error:

[image]

Sdkminversion is as follows it is above 21.
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23"

i have managed to make it able to compile using Theme.Holo.Light
however,the theme is still black in color by clearing the content in the following folder:
C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Local\Xamarin
Theme.Holo.Light is supposed to be white in colour background ,right?

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should define `Theme.Material.Light` in your `/Resource/values/style.xml`.

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.Material.Light">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="colorPrimary">#1286d9</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1286d9</item>
</style>
```

& than use it like this `@style/MyMaterialTheme`. You should use color and other features according to your preference.

Comment: It works on my another Android phone with the same code I am using but not on the existing one I am using zebra tc20 ,any idea why?

Comment: What issue are you facing? is it mobile or emulator & what version of API level, so many thing would be there to consider.